# Force CHM help window move to Index or Search tab initially

Tags: chm

How to add the feature in a CHM file to force the HTML help window move to the 'Index' or 'Search' tab when the help window popup initially?

The HtmlHelp API has options to specify either a 'HH_DISPLAY_INDEX' or 'HH_DISPLAY_SEARCH' command so the CHM help window will be foced to move to the specified tab (Index or Search tab).

Thanks for help.

CK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik the window section has options for this, but this means you must define a window.

Look at

http://chmspec.nongnu.org/latest/INI.html#HHP

paragraph 5.6.2.2.2. item 18

Comment: Thanks for answer.  Could this be done in my C++ side when calling the HtmlHelp() api with the CHM file name and command option (e.g.'HH_DISPLAY_INDEX' or 'HH_DISPLAY_SEARCH')?

Comment: Afaik if you pass it as a 3rd argument to htmlhelpa it will work I guess, but I don't know what will have prio, the above properties in the CHM or the htmlhelp call